# Default Xcode code signing identity

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, code-signing, build-settings

Hi does anyone knows a way to change the default code signing identity in Xcode?
The problem is that as I'm building the Xcode project from Unity, I'm recreating the project in every build and the Xcode signing by default is set to a wrong one.
So I have to change it by hand every time.

(I know it's possible to use the same Xcode project when building from Unity instead of creating a new one, but as I'm building in Unity using a custom plugin, I can't do that)

I'm currently using Xcode 4.3.3

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it please.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change **Code Signing Identity**, select your **target**, navigate to **Build Settings**. It's under **Signing** section.

[image]